# MQ V9.1 for Developers - Restrictions

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm looking at using MQ V9.1 for Developers (the free download). I'm sure there are restrictions re: it's sue in some ways - maybe number of messages a queue can process but can't seem to find this information. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ Advanced for Developers gives you full access to all of the MQ and MQ Advanced capabilities, with no restrictions in performance or capacity. The limitation is in support (unless you purchase that) and what it can be used for (development and unit testing only).

The details are in the license agreement (http://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?li_formnum=L-APIG-AV6HPW):

"If the Program is designated as for "Developers", the Program can only be deployed as part of Licensee's internal development and unit testing on a developer machine. A developer machine is a physical or virtual desktop environment, running a primary operating system and the Program, both of which are accessible and used by no more than one specified developer. Licensee is not authorized to use the Program for processing production workloads, simulating production workloads or testing scalability of any code, application or system. Licensee is not authorized to use any part of the Program for any other purposes without acquiring the appropriate production entitlements. "